# Derivative package: does it include square brackets with comment?

Tags: packages, mathtools

This question is only an information on the [derivative](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/derivative/derivative.pdf) package.

[image]

Just a curiosity does it include square brackets (see the green arrows) where is it possibile to put a comment (see pag. 26 of the `.pdf` of the package)?
I remember that `mathtools` package have the commands `\underbracket` and `\overbracket`.

Are they same of `mathtools` or do have used another package the authors? I'm not asking kindly for any code.

Comment: Without seeing how you produced the display is pure guessing.

Comment: @egreg Very kind egreg I have done a screenshot of the pdf to pag. 26. Now I edit, because I have forgotten. :-( I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file of user manual [`derivative.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/derivative/derivative.pdf) is [`derivative.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/derivative/derivative.tex). It uses a variant `\underbracket`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % this loads "Latin Modern Math" font, which changes the line width of \underbracket
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\low}{ O{0,0} m m }
{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__low_seq {#1}
    
    \mskip -\seq_item:Nn \l__low_seq {1} mu
    \underbracket
    {
        \mskip \seq_item:Nn \l__low_seq {1} mu
        \vphantom{f}
        #2
        \mskip \seq_item:Nn \l__low_seq {2} mu
    }
    \sb{\text{#3}}
    \mskip -\seq_item:Nn \l__low_seq {2} mu
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \low{
        \low{
            \low{4gg}{big} +
            \low[2,2]{2ff}{low}
        }{long} +
        \low{ 
            \low[1,2]{4c}{big} +
            \low[1,1]{3a}{low}
        }{short}
    }{positve} -
    \low{
        \low{
            \low[3,3]{5ee}{big} -
            \low[2,2]{3hh}{low}
        }{long} -
        \low{
            \low[1,1]{5d}{big} -
            \low[2,2]{2b}{low}
        }{short}
    }{negative}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like that means that `\low` is defined only for typesetting `derivative.pdf`, and not for use by package users.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: Surely . My thought was to finde derivative.tex. Hence, into derivative package there is  a special syntax to create the square bracket. ....✔️